# Segmentation fault strcat

Tags: c, openssl

I got a problem when reading SSL response that causes a segmentation fault. I read the response into a buffer, then append it to a malloced string and memory reset it to 0 till the response is fully read, but when I try this in a multi threaded program, after some operations it gives me segmentation fault. When I remove `strcat` it doesn't give me segmentation fault even if I run it for hours.

Example:

```
char* response = malloc(10000);
char buffer[10000] = { 0 };

while(SSL_read(ssl,buf,sizeof(buffer)) > 0){
    strcat(response,buffer);
    memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
}
```

Errors

```
free(): invalid next size (normal)
malloc_consolidate(): invalid chunk
```

I made sure of freeing both of SSL and CTX and close socket and free the malloced string.

Comment: With some arithmetic, you could be reading directly into the location you want instead of mucking around with making a copy first, then concatenating... Not enough code or details to know exactly what your data is...

Comment: Why is this question tagged `multithreading`? Nothing in your code example suggests that the code is executed by more than one thread. If it _is_ executed by more than one thread, nothing shows _how_ that code is executed by more than one thread. In what scope are `response` and `buffer` declared? There may be no reason to tag it `ssl` either if you are sure that the segfault does not happen within the `SSL_read`call.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with your code:

1. You are not dealing with C strings, you are dealing with arbitrary byte sequences. `SSL_read()` reads **bytes**, not C strings, and you cannot treat them as strings. What you read cannot be assumed to be NUL-terminated (`\0`), so you should not use `strcat`, `strlen` or other similar functions that operate on strings. Zeroing out the entire buffers just to make sure there is a terminator makes little to no sense, as the terminator could very well be found in the middle of the data.
2. You are reading data continuously in a loop into a fixed size buffer. Your code will overflow the destination buffer (`response`) very easily.
3. Not an error, but there isn't really any need for an intermediate buffer to begin with. You are needlessly copying stuff around two times (one with `SSL_read()` and one with `strcat`) when you can read directly into `response` instead. On top of that, the `memset()` to clear the contents of `buffer` also adds a third scan of the data, slowing things down even more.
4. Again, not an error, but `SSL_read()` returns `int` and uses that to return the read size. You are not really using it, but you should, as you need to keep track of how much space is left on the buffer. You would be however much better off using `size_t` to avoid unwanted problems with signed math and possible overflows. You can use [`SSL_read_ex()`](https://manned.org/SSL_read_ex.3) for this purpose.

---

Here's a snippet of code that does what you want in a more robust way:

```c
#define CHUNK_SIZE 10000

unsigned char *response = NULL;
size_t size = 0;
size_t space_left = 0;
size_t total_read = 0;
size_t n;

while (1) {
    // Allocate more memory if needed.
    if (space_left < CHUNK_SIZE) {
        unsigned char *tmp = realloc(response, size + CHUNK_SIZE);
        if (!tmp) {
            // Handle realloc error
            break;
        }

        response = tmp;
        size += CHUNK_SIZE;
        space_left += CHUNK_SIZE;
    }

    if (SSL_read_ex(ssl, response + total_read, space_left, &n)) {
        total_read += n;
        space_left -= n;
    } else {
        // Handle error
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: SSL_read_ex will always return 0 because `space_left = 0` you're putting the size of buffer to 0 so i will never read anything it will be fixed by replacing it to 1

Comment: and remove space_left -= n @Marco Bonelli

Comment: @MrBen thanks, fixed the error. The `space_left -= n` is still needed though.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialized `response()`. The arguments to `strcat()` have to be null-terminated strings.

You should also subtract 1 from the size of the buffer when calling `SSL_read()`, to ensure there will always be room for its null terminator.

```
char* response = malloc(10000);
response[0] = '\0';
char buffer[10000] = { 0 };

while(SSL_read(ssl,buf,sizeof(buffer)-1) > 0){
    strcat(response,buffer);
    memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it still doesn't work @Barmar

Comment: I'm still getting segmentation fault but when i remove it i made it run for 3 hours without any errors

Comment: @userme19429412: Your array allocations make no sense. You allocate the same size buffers for `response` and `buffer`, so if the loop runs more than once (filling `buffer` each time), you overflow `response`. Did you mean to expand `response` before each new read or before each `strcat`?

Comment: `strcat(response, buffer)` will never work if you don't check that the total size of the data does not exceed the destination buffer size... after that first `while` iteration all bets are off. Also, I'm pretty sure `SSL_read` does *not* return strings, so that `strcat` is undefined behavior in two different ways.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli He's solving the "doesn't return strings" problem by zeroing the buffer first. So there will always be a trailing null after whatever it returns.

Comment: @Barmar I mean... `SSL_read` can definitely copy zeroes *in the middle* of the data... so using string functions is wrong nonetheless. Not as bad as running beyond the end of the "string", but still.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli That's true in general, but a particular application might only deal with text data. The same thing is true with `read()`, but if you know you're reading a text file you can get away with it.